# Hibernate One-to-One Annotation behaving weirdly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am doing a one to one join to fetch result using annotation. I have two classes the first one is T_ARM_Details and the second class is ARM_Ticket_Details and T_ARM_Alert_Type. I do a one to one join using annotation but the join is not happening and is fetching data from a single table

```
package com.cts.met.bo;

import java.io.Serializable; 
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column; 
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="T_ARM_Details")

public class ARM_Ticket_Details implements Serializable {   

@Id
@Column(name="ticket_id")

  String Ticket_id;

@Column(name="arm_alert_type_id")
int arm_alert_type_id;
 /*@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(name="T_arm_alert_type",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="arm_alert_type_id",referencedColumnName="arm_alert_type_id"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name= "response_status_id"))*/

 public int getArm_alert_type_id() {
return arm_alert_type_id;
  }

public void setArm_alert_type_id(int arm_alert_type_id) {
this.arm_alert_type_id = arm_alert_type_id;
}

private T_ARM_Alert_Type t_arm_alert_type;



 //private T_SLA_Status t_sla_statuse;

public String getTicket_id() {
  return Ticket_id;
 }

public void setTicket_id(String ticket_id) {
Ticket_id = ticket_id;
} 
 @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="ARM_Ticket_Details",
 cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name="T_arm_alert_type", 
 joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="arm_alert_type_id"))//,
 referencedColumnName="arm_alert_type_id"))
  //@JoinColumn(name="arm_alert_type_id")
 public T_ARM_Alert_Type getT_arm_alert_type() {
return t_arm_alert_type;
}

public void setT_arm_alert_type(T_ARM_Alert_Type t_arm_alert_type) {
this.t_arm_alert_type = t_arm_alert_type;
}


/*@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name="T_sla_status",
   joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="resolution_status_id")//,
 //inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name= "response_status_id")
 )
 //@JoinColumn(name="status_id")
*/
/*public T_SLA_Status getT_sla_statuse() {
return t_sla_statuse;
  }

public void setT_sla_statuse(T_SLA_Status t_sla_statuse) {
this.t_sla_statuse = t_sla_statuse;
 }*/

}
```

And the next one is  as follows:

```
package com.cts.met.bo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 @Entity
  @Table(name="T_arm_alert_type")
  public class T_ARM_Alert_Type implements Serializable{
  @Id
 //@OneToOne(targetEntity=ARM_Ticket_Details.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)

//@JoinColumn(name="arm_alert_type_id",referencedColumnName="arm_alert_type_ 
  id")
  /*@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn*/
    //@JoinColumn(name="arm_alert_type_id")
   int arm_alert_type_id;

@Column(name="arm_alert_desc")
String arm_alert_desc;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ticket_id")
private ARM_Ticket_Details arm;
public ARM_Ticket_Details getArm() {
    return arm;
}
public void setArm(ARM_Ticket_Details arm) {
    this.arm = arm;
}
public int getArm_alert_type_id() {
    return arm_alert_type_id;
}
public void setArm_alert_type_id(int arm_alert_type_id) {
    this.arm_alert_type_id = arm_alert_type_id;
}
public String getArm_alert_desc() {
    return arm_alert_desc;
}
public void setArm_alert_desc(String arm_alert_desc) {
    this.arm_alert_desc = arm_alert_desc;
}

}
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/editTicket", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editTicket(HttpServletRequest request){
    String TicketId = request.getParameter("id");
    ARM_Ticket_Details ticket = pmportalService.getARMTicketById(TicketId);
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("editTicket");
    model.addObject("ticket", ticket);

    return model;
}
```

I expect a join a to happen here but it is giving the below error:

```
   select
    arm_ticket0_.ticket_id as ticket_i1_1_0_,
    arm_ticket0_.arm_alert_type_id as arm_aler2_1_0_,
    arm_ticket0_.t_arm_alert_type as t_arm_al3_1_0_ 
    from
    T_ARM_Details arm_ticket0_ 
    where
    arm_ticket0_.ticket_id=?
```

Can anyone please help? Btw I am new to hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are using Lazy `FetchType`, where you should use `EAGER` instead, or skip defining it explicitly, as it is the default `FetchType` value. Lazy loading is used for performance reasons, most commonly when you have a `OneToMany` relationship and loading too many objects, if they are not really needed affects performance on each operations. You rarely need to use lazy fetching for `OneToOne` relationship, because you are only using one additional object and that won't affect the performance of your application, except maybe in special cases of enormous objects. You can read more about different fetch types and their effect in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching).